# Finding all normal subgroups of dihedral group of order eight $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $D_8:=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b\}$, and $a^4=e$, $b^2=e$, $ba=a^{-1}b$. Find all normal subgroups of $D_8$.

What the technique to approach this? I've found the center $Z(D_8)$, and it's a normal subgroup. Are there any others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check which subgroups of $D_4$ are normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003163/how-to-check-which-subgroups-of-d-4-are-normal)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start by finding conjugacy classes, that is find the set $\{h^{-1}gh\ |\ h\in G\}$ for each $g\in G$. Normal subgroups must be unions of these classes.

Comment: This would be really better choice if he is familiar with "Normal subgroups must be unions of these classes".. I guess he is not very familiar with this... In any case this is better choice if not now but at least after a month for him...