# How to check which subgroups of $D_4$ are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How do I check which subgroups of $D_4$ are normal? Trying all elements seems very cumbersome.

So far, I know only basic theorems like Lagrange's and the homomorphism as well as the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Does $D_4$ denote the dihedral group with $4$ elements or the dihedral group generated by $s$ and a rotation of order $4$? I take it is the later since $D_4$ is abelian. =)

Comment: $D_4$ could also mean the demihyperoctahedral group of rank 4.

Comment: You certainly don't need to try all elements. But you will need to do some key computations. First - have you identified all the subgroups of $D_{4}$? If so, note that the subgroup of $D_{4}$ of order four must be normal, as it has index $2$ in $D_{4}$. The remaining subgroups are each of order $2$, and should not be too hard to check manually. You need only check against at most five elements of $D_{4}$ (why?). Comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: I didn't know that the notion is this ambiguous. I'm talking about the symmetry group of the square.

Comment: @Wertheim: Yes, I have found the subgroups.I don't see yet why subgroups with index 2 must be normal. As far as the subgroups of order two are concerned, I need to find one element of $D_4$ which contradicts the normal subgroup condition for each of the five subgroups, don't I?

Comment: @Marc "Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal" is one of the favorite early exercises in any introductory course of group theory.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I will try to prove this first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let a presentation for $D_{4}$ be given by $\langle r,s | r^{4}=s^{2}=1, rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$.

By Lagrange, any nontrivial subgroup will have either order $2$ or $4$. The cyclic subgroup generated by a rotation is a subgroup of order $4$. There are, as noted in the comments below, two other subgroups of order $4: \langle s, r^{2} \rangle = \{1, r^{2}, s, r^{2}s\}$ and $\langle rs, r^{2}\rangle = \{1, rs, r^{3}s, r^{2}\}$. It can be shown that any subgroup of index $2$ is normal; I will leave this to you as an exercise with the following suggestion. Consider the cosets of a subgroup of index $2$. What are they? Can you show the left and right cosets coincide?

Now, this leaves us with the subgroups of order $2$. You said you have identified these - great! Now, we will use a small "trick". Consider any subgroup $H= \{1, h\}$ of order $2$. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{4}$, then $gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g \in D_{4}$. Since $g1g^{-1}=1$ for all $g\in D_{4}$, we see that if $H$ is normal, $ghg^{-1}=h$ for all $g\in D_{4}$, i.e. $h$ commutes with every element of $D_{4}$. Hence, to find the normal subgroups of order $2$ in $D_{4}$, it suffices to compute the center of $G$ and identify the elements of order $2$.

To compute the center of $D_{4}$ is straightforward, which I leave to you with some hints. One, use Lagrange's theorem and the fact that $Z(D_{4})$ is a subgroup of $D_{4}$ to make some conclusions about the possible order of $Z(D_{4})$. Two, leverage what you know about the relations on the generators of $D_{4}$ to speed up computations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions! It will take me some time to figure this out exactly but I think you gave enough suggestions.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Feel free to leave a comment if some steps are unclear, I'd be happy to elaborate!

Comment: On a side note: you said that there's only the rotational subgroup of order four. But what about {${1,r^2,rs,r^3s}$} and {${1,r^2,s,r^2s}$}?

Comment: @Marc: holy moly, a dreadful oversight on my part - wasn't thinking straight. Good catch, and my mistake! I've made edits above accordingly.